# How can chrome handle PDFs better than Firefox or ImageMagick

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

In my application I import a variety of images into my database, but before storing them I convert them all to PNG using ImageMagick's convert script.

Every once in a while I encounter PDFs that can not be converted properly although they render fine in Chrome. Some of these PDFs render fine in Firefox, but mostly all of them render fine in Chrome.

The error I get when converting them using ImageMagick is:

```
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
convert: Postscript delegate failed `email.pdf': No such file or directory @ pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/611.
convert: missing an image filename `/tmp/reza%d.png' @ convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2800.
```

What are my alternatives to this problem?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Do you have example PDFs? Without concrete samples people can only guess and give generic answers which may or may not be right for your problem documents.

Comment: I wish I could, but they belong to customers and I can't post them publicly

Comment: For a start, your Ghostscript installation is some years old; the current version is 9.10.

Comment: That was it! Thanks Martin, feel free to add it as an answer and I'll mark it.